# GitHub Actions workflow triggered with files not stated in on.push.paths or on.pull_request.paths

Tags: github-actions

```
name: Console
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - "services/console/**"
      - ".github/workflows/console.yaml"
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - "services/console/**"
      - ".github/workflows/console.yaml"
```

We have the above in the following file: `.github/workflows/console.yaml`. We have other files in the source code, an example would be in `services/example-service/**`.

The problem I'm trying to fix or understand is the above workflow is triggered when files in the `services/example-service` are changed and pushed or is in a pull request. This shouldn't happen because that directory is not stated in the `on` `push` `paths` or `on` `pull_request` `paths`.

Here is the documentation for this: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-paths

Is there some scenario I've not thought of regarding this or would this be considered a bug?

The only thing I can see that it might be is this: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#git-diff-comparisons

> Note: If you push more than 1,000 commits, or if GitHub does not
> generate the diff due to a timeout, the workflow will always run.

Our code has thousands of commits, but we do not push thousands of new commits when updating.

Comment: Did you add those PATHs on master after PRs were created ?
Does it happen for newly created PRs?
Problem with PR is that they are using workflows from the moment they are created - you will have to rebase them onto master to see the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason was after contacting GitHub support was that pushes use two dot diffs while PRs use three dot diffs.

The two dot diff caused a trigger because we rebased the branch onto master which had changes to the directory stated and then we force pushed. This caused the diff between the new forced pushed branch and the immediate commit before on the branch to includes a hell of a lot of diffs, some of which were in the stated directroy.

Comment: Could you include what you changed in the workflow file? I am having the same issue but it is not apparent what to change.